# Laptop shuts down at 40%-50% only on Ubuntu

Tags: gnome, 17.04, shutdown, battery

I bought my laptop one year ago, I installed Windows 10 and it was great. The battery lasted 3 hours before I had to charge it again. But recently I installed Ubuntu and now it barely lasts 1 hour. When it reachs 40-50% it kinda shuts down. The screen goes black but the fans start spinning like crazy and it only happens on Ubuntu. Does anyone knows how to solve it?

Laptop specs: 
Intel i7-6700HQ
Nvidia GeForce GTX 950M
Ubuntu 17.04 Gnome

Comment: sounds like a heat issue not a battery issue.

Comment: But it only happens when i'm on battery at 40% and only on Ubuntu. On windows 10 it works just fine

Comment: @ravery I have the same problem on two different laptops. An ASUS K55VD an an ASUS X55V. The former shuts down at ~ 33% battery, the other at ~ 60%. It only happens on Linux, and the thermals are fine (CPU is at ~45C for the first, and at ~53C for the second). On the first one I've been using Linux since 2014 and this problem only appeared last year IIRC (2017). I also want to mention that the first uses Arch (also tried Ubuntu but the problem persists) and the second Ubuntu, so it might be a kernel problem rather than Ubuntu-specific. As I said, it's just on Linux - Windows is fine

Comment: natept, what's your laptop model? I wonder if yours is also an ASUS

Comment: No, it's not an Asus. It's a Clevo N550RC. As you said, I think the problem is with Linux, not just Ubuntu, because I tried with Fedora and I had the same problems

Comment: I also have the same issue on the Clevo P955ER (Eurocom Q6) with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.